# Embedding Map Activity in another activity in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, mapactivity

I would like to make the google maps viewable in another activity, that is, it does not take the entire screen. Is it possible to embed a google map map activty in another activity, so that, let's say, it takes half or 3/4 of the screen please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

You can use MapView as any other view - position and size as you like.

If you want to place MapView into ScrollView here is good solution to make sure it works correctly: [MapView inside a ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546108/mapview-inside-a-scrollview)

Answer (score 0):

You can include MapView in layout and code for the same in `MapActivity` with the portion you want for it.

Why do you want for it in another activity?

Comment: I basically have an activity which contains other information, and it wouldn't b ideal to have the map view on a seperate activity. do you mean including an inner layout inside the parent activity?

Comment: Can't you manage this *other information* inside MapActivity?

Comment: Probably I can if the MapActivity extends Activity, however, I would need to resize the MapView itself.