# iScroll on Android: Google maps markers click not working

Tags: google-maps, cordova, iscroll

I'm creating an Android app with Cordova. I'm currently using iScroll for smooth scrolling and have set the following iScroll options click = true and tap = true.

All the clicks/taps work fine with the exception of all click events on the map, map markers.

If I remove the iScroll options then only the map click events work and not all the others in the app.

How can I solve this and what is going on?

Comment: I assume you're using a MapView. You'll probably have to create a custom MapView and override the touch event. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546108/mapview-inside-a-scrollview

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using 'onmouseover' event instead of 'onclick'.