# MapView doesn't work inside ScrollView - Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, android, scrollview, appcelerator, android-mapview

I need to put a mapView inside a ScrollView, but when I try to drag the map in the same direction as the scrollview, the scroll moves instead of the map, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546108/mapview-inside-a-scrollview) question here in SO, the problem seems to be the exact same, however I am using Javascript.

my xml looks something like this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <View>
        <View id = "mapView">
        </View>
        <View>
        <!-- stuff added programmatically -->
        </View>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

One more thing, this problem only happens in Android, not iOS.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, put your mapview inside a nested_scroll_view.

```
<ScrollView>
    <View>
        <NestedScrollView>
            <View id = "mapView"/>
        </NestedScrollView>
        <View>
        <!-- stuff added programmatically -->
        </View>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

I had a same problem but with some other view. This may or may not help.